# JPA Criteria Group By

Tags: java

I have got the following problem, maybe somebody can help me.

I wrote a SQL query:

```
SELECT v.bezeichnung, count(*) as total  
FROM veranstaltung v 
    JOIN  auffuehrung a  ON  v.id = a.veranstaltung_id
    JOIN  platz p  ON p.auffuehrung_id = a.id
    JOIN   transaktion t ON t.id = p.transaktion_id  
WHERE t.status = 2 AND (a.datumuhrzeit + 30 DAY) >= CURRENT_DATE  
GROUP BY v.bezeichnung  
ORDER BY total DESC
```

I have to implement it in JPA but everything works except GROUP BY... it can't be grouped..

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();  
CriteriaQuery<Veranstaltung> query = builder.createQuery(Veranstaltung.class);  
Root<Veranstaltung> rootVeranstaltung = query.from(Veranstaltung.class);                        query.where(builder.equal(rootVeranstaltung.join("auffuehrungen").join("plaetze").join("transaktion").<Transaktionsstatus>get("status"), Transaktionsstatus.BUCHUNG));  
query.groupBy(rootVeranstaltung);  
List<Veranstaltung> result = this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();  
return list;
```

I haven't finished the code yet, e.g. the COUNT..
should i write `COUNT` already before `GROUP BY` or would it work without `COUNT`?